# How to use return without ending the for loop in python?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, return

I am creating a project on examination system.
Here,I have a database (db3) called questionpapers which contains 6 question papers in the form of a table.
I want to return the names of these papers in my webpage in the form of hyperlinks.

This is my python code:

```
@app.route('/qsetdisplay',methods=['GET','POST'])
def qset_display():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("found template")
        cursor4 = db3.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor4.execute("show tables")
        papers = cursor4.fetchall()
        print("papers:",papers)
        names = []
        for p in papers:
            print("for p in papers:")
            print("p:",p)
            value = list(p.values())
            print("value:",value)
            names.append(value)
        print("names:",names)
        l = len(names)
        for i in range(l):
            print(names[i][0])
            return(names[i][0])
        return "THESE ARE THE AVAILABLE PAPERS"
    return render_template('profile.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The return statement returns only the first element and ends the loop.

This is my compiler output:

```
found template
papers: [{'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'pcdata'}, {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'physics1'}, {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'physics_test'}, {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'sample'}, {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'sample1'}, {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'samplea'}]
for p in papers:
p: {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'pcdata'}
value: ['pcdata']
for p in papers:
p: {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'physics1'}
value: ['physics1']
for p in papers:
p: {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'physics_test'}
value: ['physics_test']
for p in papers:
p: {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'sample'}
value: ['sample']
for p in papers:
p: {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'sample1'}
value: ['sample1']
for p in papers:
p: {'Tables_in_questionpapers': 'samplea'}
value: ['samplea']
names: [['pcdata'], ['physics1'], ['physics_test'], ['sample'], ['sample1'], ['samplea']]
pcdata
```

I tried yield but it didn't work.
I am using flask and pymysql packages.

How can I crct this code?

And also is there any way to return the elements in the form of hyperlinks?

I want to return all the 6 names of the question papers in my webpage

Comment: Well, that's what `return` does - it finishes execution and returns the value. What do you want to get as an output of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at jinja2, you would just pass the variable into your html code and in html code, you could do a `for` loop and create hyperlinks

```py
@app.route('/qsetdisplay',methods=['GET','POST'])
def qset_display():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("found template")
        cursor4 = db3.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor4.execute("show tables")
        papers = cursor4.fetchall()
        print("papers:",papers)
        names = []
        for p in papers:
            print("for p in papers:")
            print("p:",p)
            value = list(p.values())
            print("value:",value)
            names.append(value)
        print("names:",names)
        l = len(names)
        for i in range(l):
            print(names[i][0])
            return(names[i][0])
        #you should delete this line, it's no use
    return render_template('profile.html', names=names)
```

In your html code

```html
{% for name in names %}
<a href="{{ url_for('name') }}">{{ names }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank u!! Your answer was helpful

Comment: I just want to know for what names=names is for in the code.

Comment: The first ```names``` means what will be the variable's name in jinja2 and the second ```names``` means what is the variable's name in python. Do you understand?

Comment: Thank u for the help sir!!